# Testing React Regex String in Jest -Failing

Tags: reactjs, regex, typescript, testing, jestjs

I created an Input component with a prop called regexStr.  The type is a string and my functioning code is the following:

```
    if(regexStr){
         const newRegexStr = new RegExp(regexStr)
         const alteredInput = e.target.replace(newRegexStr),"");
         e.target.value = alteredInput;
         setInputValue(e.target.value)

}
```

The code is working exactly as expected.  When I pass a regex string it runs the regex.  My issue comes when trying to test.  In my test file I have the following:

```
it('should blah blah blah'), () => {
   const {getByTestId} = render (
       <Input
          id="name"
          regexStr="/[^A-Za-z]/"
       ></Input>
)
   const input = getByTestId('input)
   fireEvent.change(input, { target: {value: 'hello123' }})
   expect(input).toHaveValue('hello'))
```

I am not sure why the test keeps failing.  My actual output is "hello123" vs "hello".  I have tried changing several things and nothing seems to be working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Remove slashes, `regexStr="[^A-Za-z]"`

Comment: When I remove the slashes, my test still fails with an output of "hello23".  It removed the 1 but left the 23

Comment: Then add `g`, `new RegExp(regexStr, "g")`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the code by removing the slashes around the pattern (that is specified via a string, not a regex literal) and compile the regex object with the global `g` flag to remove all found occurrences:

```js
if(regexStr){
     const newRegexStr = new RegExp(regexStr, "g")           // <-- HERE
     const alteredInput = e.target.replace(newRegexStr),"");
     e.target.value = alteredInput;
     setInputValue(e.target.value)
}

it('should blah blah blah'), () => {
   const {getByTestId} = render (
       <Input
          id="name"
          regexStr="[^A-Za-z]"                              // <-- HERE
       ></Input>
)
   const input = getByTestId('input)
   fireEvent.change(input, { target: {value: 'hello123' }})
   expect(input).toHaveValue('hello'))
```